# how do i instantiate an array based on user input

Tags: java, arrays, instantiation

I am confused on how to instantiate the array using input from the user, the spot where i believe it should be is next to the comment right here
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Sales
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] sales;

    sales = getSales();
    printSales(sales);
    printSummary(sales);
  }

  private static int[] getSales()
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] temp;

    System.out.print("Enter the number of salespeople: ");
    temp = _____________;   // RIGHT HERE
```

Comment: What's confusing you? The instantiation, taking the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write something like:

```
temp = new int[input.nextInt()];
```